# android crop image but let user decide output size

Tags: android, image, widget, crop

The current "com.android.camera.action.CROP" API lets the program specify pre-defined outputX/Y:

```
// this defines the output bitmap size
intent.putExtra("outputX", 100);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 100);
```

But can we not to specify the size up-front, but take from what the user actually cropped as output size?

E.g. with the above code, the cropped output will always be a squared 100 x 100 image taken from the original image, while the user may want crop a 50 x 100 image.  The output size should not be pre-defined.

Any idea how to do this?

Or is there any better image cropping library which can do this other than com.android.camera.action.CROP?

Thanks.